# Extra effects does not appear on Dell Inspiron 5010

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, compiz, graphics

I'm using Dell Inspiron 5010. Recently, I installed 10.10 Ubuntu Netbook Edition within Windows 7, but there's no extra graphical effects. Once I try to activate them, why does it say graphic effects could not be changed? My laptop has laptop uses 1 GB VGA as well.

Answer (score 2):

In a regular Desktop Edition install, the graphic effects you are looking for are done by a program called **Compiz**.

The Unity interface you see in Ubuntu Netbook Edition uses **Mutter**, a new program that also generates graphical effects.

Since Mutter and Compiz are used to do the same thing, they cannot be used together. In short, it's not possible to get those effects on 10.10 Netbook Edition.

Look forward to 11.04 Natty Narwhal, it uses Compiz for Unity with even cooler desktop effects!

Comment: @Vinothan, just so you know, there'll be no separate Desktop or Netbook Edition in 11.04, as only Unity will be used. And [accept this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) if you think it has solved your issue.